# Xamarin forms page not loaded properly for PopPageModel using navigation stack in FreshMVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation, freshmvvm

We are using FreshMVVM in our application. We are using CoreMethods.PopPageModel based on NavigationStack count. While navigating the required page, that page not loaded properly. In xamarin forms ios it's working fine. For xamarin forms android not working fine. We are using below code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    await CoreMethods.PopPageModel(i == (CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1), animate: false);
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: "not working fine" - what happens? Nothing shows?  Did you check Output pane in VS, to see if any errors or warnings, when it executes that line?

Comment: And where did you call the pop method?

Comment: What's the issue? You are popping the page models meaning that you are removing them, are you not navigating back to the correct page? When you say its not loaded properly, what do you mean?